# Can I change webpack version in spfx's build tools?

Tags: spfx, webpack

So I'm working with spfx v1.8.2 and I cannot find any options or documentation  even to solutions how upgrade or override webpack used by that build tools.

Is there a possibility to do that without any hacks and tricks?
(Yes, I know that build tools give possibility to override generated configuration for webpack, but I need to upgrade webpack version)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found solution to that and it is quite simple,

**Steps:**

- Remove `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` (or respectively `package-lock.json`).
- Add to resolutions in `package.json`, `"**/webpack": "<your-version>"`
- Install all dependencies (`npm i` or `yarn install`).